# Python 2.7: Remove duplicates from csv based on conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a csv file that has the following format:

```
Username,Name,Phone,Email,Country,Login
John23,John Doe,99999999,johndoe@yahoo.com,Italy,1585589097.787715
John23,John Doe,99999999,johndoe@yahoo.com,Italy,1585652050.037622
```

I want to remove rows that contain duplicate 'Username' and just keep the row with the highest value in 'Login'.

Right now I have the following, but it only remove identical rows:

```
#remove duplicates and generate new csv
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

with open('jornalnoticias.csv','r') as f, open('jornalnoticias_full.csv','w') as out_file:
    out_file.writelines(unique_everseen(f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read in the CSV file with [`csv.DictReader`](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), group items by `UserName` using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and output the max `Login` rows with [`csv.DictWriter`](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

The below should work for **Python2.7**:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
from collections import defaultdict

with open("jornalnoticias.csv", mode="rb") as fin, open("jornalnoticias_full.csv", mode="w") as fout:
    reader = DictReader(fin)
    writer = DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)

    # Group by username
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        groups[row["Username"]].append(row)

    # Write to CSV file
    writer.writeheader()
    for username, group in groups.items():

        # Get max login and write row
        highest_login = max(group, key=lambda x: float(x['Login']))
        writer.writerow(highest_login)
```

**jornalnoticias_full.csv**

```
Username,Name,Phone,Email,Country,Login
John23,John Doe,99999999,johndoe@yahoo.com,Italy,1585652050.037622
```

**Note:** It might be a good idea to move to the latest **Python 3.8**. Some things have changed a bit since **Python 2.7**.